# Minecraft Xbox One Edition /say command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im making a world in Minecraft that uses the command /say a lot. When I join the world, everything works fine, until I try to use the command /say in a command block. All the other commands work fine, but when I use /say, it works only for my split screener and not me? Can anyone help me out?